# Publishing Gradle version catalog to maven local

Tags: maven, gradle, build.gradle, version, publish

I am trying to publish a gradle version catalog to mavenLocal repository in order to share versions between multiple projects.

TLDR; [project on github](https://github.com/lorenzjosten/gradle-version-catalogs) publishing of version catalog does not work.

I was doing as described in the official [docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/platforms.html).

In my ./gradle folder i have a *.toml file which describes my version catalog.

Importing it successfully works via

```kotlin
// settings.gradle.kts

rootProject.name = "gradle-version-catalogs"

enableFeaturePreview("VERSION_CATALOGS")

dependencyResolutionManagement {
    versionCatalogs {
        create("quarkus") {
            from(files("gradle/quarkus.versions.toml"))
        }
    }
}
```

The build script looks like this:

```kotlin
// build.gradle.kts

group = "de.lj"
version = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

plugins {
    `version-catalog`
    `maven-publish`
}

publishing {
    publications {
        create<MavenPublication>("quarkus") {
            println("Version Catalogs:")
            versionCatalogs.catalogNames.forEach { println(it) }
            from(components["versionCatalog"])
        }
    }
}
```

Running the gradle publish task results in an artifact de.lj.gradle.version-catalogs:1.0-SNAPSHOT being published to my mavenLocal repository. But there is no de.lj.quarkus which I would like to create.

I am using gradle version 7.3.3 with plugins version-catalog, maven-publish. I pushed my project to [github](https://github.com/lorenzjosten/gradle-version-catalogs).

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: The block

```
// settings.gradle.kts

versionCatalogs {
    ...
}
```

is only needed for projects, that IMPORT the published version catalog. It's not needed in the project defining the version catalog.
Instead build the version catalog from the *.toml file:

```
// build.gradle.kts 

catalog {
    versionCatalog {
        from(files("./gradle/quarkus.versions.toml"))
    }
}
```

In order to have a version catalog published to mavenLocal with the Coordinates ${my.groupId}:${my.artifactId}:${my.version} set

```
// settings.gradle.kts 

rootProject.name = "${my.groupId}"

// build.gradle.kts

group = "${my.groupId}"
version = "${my.version}"
```

Other projects can now reference the versionCatalog with

```
// settings.gradle.kts

rootProject.name = "version-catalog-import"

enableFeaturePreview("VERSION_CATALOGS")

dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
    }

    versionCatalogs { 
        create("${my.reference}").from("${my.groupId}:${my.artifactId}:${my.version}")
    }
}

// build.gradles.kts

plugins {
    `kotlin-dsl`
    `version-catalog`
}

dependencies {
    implementation(${my.reference})
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Following this almost worked, the problem was that the TOML file published was empty.
I managed to get it to work adding the following code in the "build.gradle.kts" :

```
catalog {
    versionCatalog {
        from(files("./gradle/quarkus.versions.toml"))
    }
}
```

So the whole file ends as:

```
/// build.gradle.kts

group = "de.lj"
version = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"
plugins {
    `version-catalog`
    `maven-publish`
}
catalog {
    versionCatalog {
        from(files("gradle/quarkus.versions.toml"))
    }
}
publishing {
    publications {
        create<MavenPublication>("quarkus") {
            from(components["versionCatalog"])
        }
    }
}
```

Also, this block of code in "settings.gradle.kts" we can remove:

```
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    versionCatalogs {
        create("quarkus") {
            from(files("gradle/quarkus.versions.toml"))
        }
    }
}
```

resulting in:

```
/// settings.gradle.kts

rootProject.name = "gradle-version-catalogs"
enableFeaturePreview("VERSION_CATALOGS")
```

With these, I could use the published version catalog from other projects.

Comment: Nice,  I too was noticing that the published toml file was empty and this solution worked perfectly for me.  In my case, I didn't remove the versionCatalogs block from the settings.gradle.kts file.  The reason I didn't was that I needed to get the version number of the version catalog I'm publishing, and that version number is stored in the version catalog that I'm publishing.  So, by leaving it defined in the settings.gradle.kts file I was able to get that version number.  You can't do that if you only define the version catalog in the build.gradle.kts file.

Answer (score 1):

```kts
plugins {
    `version-catalog`
    `maven-publish`
}
catalog { versionCatalog { from(files("../gradle/libs.versions.toml")) } }
publishing {
    publications {
        create<MavenPublication>("maven") {
            group = "com.k4dima"
            artifactId = "version-catalog"
            version = "0.0.1"
            from(components["versionCatalog"])
        }
    }
}
```

```bash
./gradlew publishToMavenLocal
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also publish the version catalog using the following:

```
    create<MavenPublication>("VersionCatalog") {
        groupId = "com.quarkus"
        artifactId = "com.quarkus.version.catalog"
        version = libs.versions.toml.get()
        artifact("../gradle/quarkus.versions.toml")
    }
```

In the above, the version catalog itself contains the version of the TOML file.  The only difference in publishing the artifact directly instead of using the component versionCatalog is that when you publish it as a component, the TOML file gets the following prepended to the original artifact:

```
 #
 # This file has been generated by Gradle and is intended to be consumed by Gradle
 #
 [metadata]
 format.version = "1.1"
```

At this time, I don't know if it's useful to have that metadata or not.

Comment: It also occurred to me that if you are going to publish the version catalog via the artifact method, you should also include its creation in your settings file.  By doing that, you are assuring yourself that the TOML file is at least syntactically well formed.